# Apply column-wise custom function to 2 dataframes, creating a new dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have 2 dataframes:

```
df_up = pd.DataFrame({"u1":[2,-3,5,0], 
                      "u2":[1,0,5,-2]},
                      index=["ta","tb","tc","td"])

df_tt = pd.DataFrame({"q1":[1,0,1,0], 
                      "q2":[1,0,1,1],
                      "q3":[0,1,0,0]},
                      index=["ta","tb","tc","td"])
```

I want to create a new dataframe that calculates the cosine similarity between all columns of df_up and all columns of df_tt. Both dataframes have the same number of rows.Ideally, the solution would work with a custom function, such as:

```
from scipy import spatial
def cosine_similarity(array_1, array_2):
    return 1 - spatial.distance.cosine(array_1,array_2)
```

The result would look like this:

```
    u1       u2
q1  0.8029   0.7745
q2  0.6556   0.4216
q3  -0.4866  0.0
```

Is there an "elegant" way of solving this or is iterating through the 2 dataframes the only way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A generic way is to use `corr` with a `callable` method, see below,

```
# There was a typo in the original method: array_1, array_2

def cosine_similarity(array1, array2):
    return 1 - spatial.distance.cosine(array1,array2)

output = (pd.concat([df_up, df_tt], axis=1)
            .corr(method=cosine_similarity)
            .drop(columns=df_tt.columns, index=df_up.columns))
```

Comment: Thanks for the typo hint

Comment: Your solution works, and is generic (which I like), but it is quite inefficient with large datasets because it calculates the correlation between all rows in the concatenated dataframe. Is there any way to get around this inefficiency?

Comment: @d_gnz unfotunately not with corr, as it basically runs a n*n python loop

Answer (score 2):

Solution from `cdist`

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist
ary=(1-cdist(df_up.T.values, df_tt.T.values, metric='cosine')).T
df=pd.DataFrame(ary,columns=df_up.columns,index=df_tt.columns)
Out[258]: 
          u1        u2
q1  0.802955  0.774597
q2  0.655610  0.421637
q3 -0.486664  0.000000
```

Comment: Is there any way to do the cdist part generically, so with a custom function?

Comment: @d_gnz then you need define your own function